# The application [name] has stopped unexpectedly. (AIR/FlashDevelop)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I am a newcomer to Flash and Actionscript, and am trying to build a test application to run on an Android device or emulator. (Running it with the Flash player works fine).

When I deploy and run my test APK with `goto android-test` in `Run.bat` on either an emulator (ARM-based) or a real device (Nexus 7), it terminates with `The application [name] has stopped unexpectedly`.

When I try to debug, on the other hand using `goto android-debug`, it just comes up with a blank screen.

In FlashDevelop, I see no further log messages indicating what kind of error occurs on the device or emulator.

Previously, I had the problem that it could not build the APK because of the namespace in the `application.xml`, which was:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0">
```

I wonder whether it got the `14.0` from the Flash Player version I set in a previous project. After changing that to `3.1` to match what I think the version of the AIR runtime is, it compiled the APK, but now I have this problem.

I am using **Flex SDK 4.6** and **FlashDevelop 4.6.2.5**.

Here is my main class:

```
package ceronio.net
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Martin
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);

            // touch or gesture?
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        }

        private function deactivate(e:Event):void 
        {
        }

    }

}
```

And this is my `application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.1">

    <id>ceronio.net.mobile2</id>
    <versionNumber>0.1</versionNumber>
    <supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
    <filename>mobile2</filename>

    <name>mobile2</name>
    <description></description>
    <copyright></copyright>

    <android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[

            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
              <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
            </manifest>

        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <iPhone> 
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[ 

            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
            <string>NO</string>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>  
            <true/>
            <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
            <true/>

            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <!-- iPhone support -->
                <string>1</string> 
                <!-- iPad support -->
                <!--<string>2</string>-->
            </array>

        ]]></InfoAdditions> 
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone> 

    <initialWindow>
        <title>mobile2</title>
        <content>mobile2.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    </initialWindow>

    <icon>
        <image48x48>icons/icon_48.png</image48x48>
        <image57x57>icons/icon_57.png</image57x57>
        <image72x72>icons/icon_72.png</image72x72>
    </icon>

</application>
```

Thanks to Hiemanshu's comment which pointed me to logcat. Using that, I got the following log, which makes me wonder whether it cannot reference the AIR runtime. I did follow the instructions to first deploy the runtime with `InstallAirRuntime.bat`, however.

```
D/dalvikvm(  659): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.adobe.air/lib/libCore.so 0x4051c380

I/dalvikvm(  659): Failed resolving Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView$2; interface 153 'Landroid/view/View$OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener;'

W/dalvikvm(  659): Link of class 'Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView$2;' failed

E/dalvikvm(  659): Could not find class 'com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView$2', referenced from method com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.DoSetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener

W/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 213 (Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView$2;) in Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView;

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0008 in Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView;.DoSetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener ()V

I/dalvikvm(  659): Could not find method android.view.View.setSystemUiVisibility, referenced from method com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.clearFullScreen

W/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 395: Landroid/view/View;.setSystemUiVisibility (I)V

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001a

I/dalvikvm(  659): Could not find method android.view.View.setSystemUiVisibility, referenced from method com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.setFullScreen

W/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 395: Landroid/view/View;.setSystemUiVisibility (I)V

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x001c

I/dalvikvm(  659): Could not find method android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.getCurrentSpanX, referenced from method com.adobe.air.gestures.AIRGestureListener.onScale

W/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 367: Landroid/view/ScaleGestureDetector;.getCurrentSpanX ()F

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0040

I/dalvikvm(  659): Could not find method android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.getPreviousSpanX, referenced from method com.adobe.air.gestures.AIRGestureListener.onScale

W/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 372: Landroid/view/ScaleGestureDetector;.getPreviousSpanX ()F

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x009a

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: dead code 0x0043-0067 in Lcom/adobe/air/gestures/AIRGestureListener;.onScale (Landroid/view/ScaleGestureDetector;)Z

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: dead code 0x009d-0115 in Lcom/adobe/air/gestures/AIRGestureListener;.onScale (Landroid/view/ScaleGestureDetector;)Z

D/dalvikvm(  659): VFY: dead code 0x0136-013a in Lcom/adobe/air/gestures/AIRGestureListener;.onScale (Landroid/view/ScaleGestureDetector;)Z

W/OrientationEventListener(  659): Cannot detect sensors. Not enabled

W/dalvikvm(  659): No implementation found for native Lcom/adobe/air/AIRWindowSurfaceView;.nativeOnFormatChangeListener (I)V

D/AndroidRuntime(  659): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(  659): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(  659): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeOnFormatChangeListener

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.nativeOnFormatChangeListener(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at com.adobe.air.AIRWindowSurfaceView.surfaceChanged(AIRWindowSurfaceView.java:683)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:549)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:348)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.SurfaceView.draw(SurfaceView.java:334)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1862)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1522)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1258)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

E/AndroidRuntime(  659):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager(   61):   Force finishing activity air.air.ceronio.net.mobile2/.AppEntry

W/ActivityManager(   61): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40628908 air.air.ceronio.net.mobile2/.AppEntry}

D/dalvikvm(  305): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 54% free 2542K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 72ms

W/ActivityManager(   61): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{40628908 air.air.ceronio.net.mobile2/.AppEntry}

D/dalvikvm(  315): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 54% free 2539K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 100ms

D/dalvikvm(  217): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12K, 55% free 2595K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 74ms
```

Comment: Can you please add a logcat to this?

Comment: Ah, that sounds helpful. Where would I get that?

Comment: You can use http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1726238 as a reference on how to do it.

Comment: OK, found docu on Android site. Will add to post. Thanks very much for the hint!

Comment: You could try overlaying the AIR SDK in the Flex SDK, so you're sure you have the latest SDK. Here are some general instructions on overlaying http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html

Comment: @CristinaGeorgescu Please post this as an answer. I am busy testing it, but it seems it may resolve my problem. Have tested with other IDEs, but in FlashDevelop, it requires a bit more effort.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one AIR version available at any time when creating an actionscript AIR project this is as opposed to flex project where you can target different SDK versions. FB did set the correct version for you: 14.0 and that is the version you need to work with. Trying to set it to 3.1 can only generate errors. I think in your case the main problem is that you have a huge collection of mistakes and errors that simply accumulate and make the whole project fail. Solution, start fresh with a new empty project, compile and test, if it doesn't work come back here with the results (and this time those results will not be mixed with other errors). My guess is that it will work just fine and you simply need to not mess up the project settings.

Comment: I believe the Flash version is 14.0, but the AIR version is 3.1.

Comment: 3.1 is an outdated version, for example it would not work for publishing for ios. As for Android Adobe recommends publishing with the latest AIR SDK 14.0. Why is it so important for you to publish with a 2 years old outdated SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overlaying the AIR SDK in the Flex SDK, so you're sure you have the latest SDK. Here are some general instructions on overlaying http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html

Also, I think that in Flash Develop you can install several Flex SDKs and choose the one suited for your project. You can find here how to add new SDKs http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Configuration#Configuring_the_Flex_SDK
Then you can open your project in Flash Develop and go to Project > Properties and select the 3.9 SDK and it should work. I find that configuring Flash Develop is pretty tricky.